# Where can I ask about issues with my company's audio recording software?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am a system administrator for a company that does in music publishing and media production. We run five studios on two locations. We are experiencing problems with our setup including a proprietary Audio recording software, MacOS and afp shares on a major brand NAS. The software editor won't help us and I must find a solution.

If the Stack Exchange community is a place where I could get help, how should I do it? I don't want to infringe on any guidelines. What is the policy about citing brands? What if I was interested in hiring someone would seem able to solve the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you should be on either [SF] or [SU] . The first site is for questions about systems administration, the second is for general computer usage. It sounds like your problem is more about this particular piece of software, so consider the latter.

Comment: Regarding the question if you should hire someone - that's out of scope for Stack Exchange. Regarding brands - it's fine to specify what software you are using if it's relevant to the question. If you post an answer recommending software (or any product or service), you should disclose any affiliation you might have with these.

Comment: "with our setup including a proprietary Audio recording software" - have you tried contacting **the authors of the software**?